# Custom environment variable not being pulled from environment.prod.ts

Tags: angular

I have a environment.prod.ts and environment.ts with and extra serviceUrl variable like this:

```
//environment.prod.ts
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  serviceUrl: 'Myprod'
};

//environment.ts
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  serviceUrl: 'Mydev'
};
```

On my component I am using it to see if being switch

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 't..';

  environmentInformation: string = environment.serviceUrl;

  private isProduction: boolean = environment.production;

  if (isProduction) {
    enableProdMode();
  }
}
```

But if I run `ng serve --prod -o` to check that the api url is changing I got this error

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(13,48): error TS2339: Property 'serviceUrl' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.
```

I have tried with ng serve -o and it work and I have tried with dev and also work and display my service url. No sure is this is a bug on angular because it is an easy process.

Comment: What does your `environments` config look like in `.angular-cli.json`?

Comment: "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }

Comment: if I try to  build changing the environment to dev but keeping target tot prod it does not have issues: ng build --prod -e dev

Comment: Did you find any solution for this, cause I am having same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It's strange i get the same issue when i try it on local with constant as serviceUrl, can you replace as below and it is working for me

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  serviceEndPoint: 'Mydev'
}
```

and then in component

```
 private  environmentInformation = environment.serviceEndPoint;
```